# How to write a CRAN-publishable package linked against Intel MKL?

Tags: r, rcpp, intel-mkl

I am writing an `R` package that ideally needs the `vdCdfNormInv` function from the `Intel MKL`.

**How do I configure the `NAMESPACE` file and the `makevar` file?**

There is a scalar version of this function from `Rmath.h`. However, if possible, the MKL version should have better performance.

Comment: Did you already try something? If yes, what went wrong? Howewer, MKL being licensed by Intel, there is probably no way to make it CRAN-publishable, but I might be wrong

Comment: I only found that you could change the `PKG_LIBS` variable in the `Makevar` file to link the default BLAS and LAPACK libraries used by R. I do not know how to link to an external library like MKL. Thanks though, linking to MKL might be not allowed.

Comment: Ok, did you check the links giver here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18570526/how-to-build-a-r-package-which-use-rcpp-with-external-c-libraries

Comment: if you don't get an answer here in a reasonable amount of time, you might try the `r-package-devel@r-project.org` mailing list ...  Have you done some benchmarks of the Intel MKL version vs. `pnorm` in the Rmath library ... ?

Comment: Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38090206/linking-intels-math-kernel-library-mkl-to-r-on-windows), I suppose you'd have to add MKL to `SystemRequirements` in the `DESCRIPTION` file, but I don't know what would be needed in the `Makevars` file

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/48037641/8416610 for some possible linking flags. You should use a `configure` script to test for the presence of MKL. You can then use pre-processor macros as suggested by @thc to destinguish between MKL and no-MKL usage.

Comment: @BenBolker, not specifically. It will be interesting to test out ) However, the `pnorm` from `Rmath` does not assume standard normal, which may cost more FLOPs.

Comment: @Chelmy88, thanks. I checked the manual and the short paper on Rcpp but did not find examples on linking external library.

Comment: @RalfStubner thanks. It seems easier if R is built with the MKL. It's a good point that I should distinguish between MKL-equipped environment and others.

Answer (score 4):

Use C++ preprocessor macros.  Here's am example:

```
double result;
#ifdef INTEL_MKL_VERSION 
result = vdCdfNormInv(...);
#else
result = vdCdfNormInv_generic(...);
#endif
```

Alternatively, you can just throw an error (`std::runtime_error` or `Rcpp::stop`) if `INTEL_MKL_VERSION` is not defined.

But I think if you submit a package to CRAN, you should take the effort to make it available to people without MKL, even if it is slower.

See also reference:
[Using Predefined Preprocessor Symbols for Intel® MKL Version-Dependent Compilation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-windows-developer-guide-using-predefined-preprocessor-symbols-for-intel-mkl-version-dependent-compilation)